# Having trouble running/installing camelcase

Tags: python, pip, camelcasing

I am trying to run camelCase and install it the code I used for installing it is

```
   C:\Users\Your Name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts>pip install camelcase
```

which gave me the result of

```
   C:\\Users\\Your Name\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36-32\\Scripts>pip install camelcase
```

which made me think it installed it but when I tried to import camelCase using `import camelCase`
it gave me the result of

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'camelcase'
```

(I have Python 3.8.3 BTW so it already has PIP)

Answer (score 1):

Import the `camelcase` package using lowercase letters. As an example:

```
from camelcase import CamelCase
c = CamelCase()
s = 'this is a sentence that needs camelcasing!'
print(c.hump(s))
```

Comment: ironic mistake :p

Comment: Ironically named package and ironically designed API, I daresay. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem. To solve this in windows:

1. Find where the project interpreter is located, for example in Pycharm you can find it here :Settings\Project:<project_name>\Python Interpreter
2. Open cmd and active the same pass.
3. Try to install your package in that pass by using: pip install

That may solve the problem.